# A Mellin Transform of a generating function

Tags: generating-functions, integral-transforms, catalan-numbers, mellin-transform

I am trying to find the Mellin transform of the function
$$
 G(z) = \sum_{k \ge 1} C_k\left( 1- \exp \left( \frac{-z}{4^k} \right )\right),
$$
where $C_k$ denotes the $k$-th Catalan number ($C_k = \frac 1{n+1}\binom{2n}n $), yet the function doesn't seem to have a transform.
Follwing the paper [Mellin Transforms and Asymtotics: Harmonic Sums](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/mellin-harm.pdf) (mainly Section 3) by Philippe Flajolet et al, we first separate the Dirichlet series from the harmonic sum, and, in order to stay consistent with their treatment, switch $G(z)$ for $G(1/z)$. In their notation, using
$$
 \lambda_k = C_k,\, \mu_k = 4^k,\, g(z) = 1-\exp(-1/z)
$$
we get the Dirichlet series
$$
 \Lambda(s) = \sum_{k \ge 1 } C_k 4^{-ks} \approx \sum_{k \ge 1 } \frac 1 {\sqrt{ \pi k^3}}4^{k(1-s)}.
$$
The problem now is that $\Lambda(s)$ converges for $\mathrm{Re}(z) > 1$, and the base function $g(z)$ has the fundamental strip of $(0,1)$, meaning that we can't factor the series from the base function following their Lemma 2, nor can we read of the asymptotics of $G(z)$ by using the singular expansion of $G^*(z)$ (which is what I would like to do).
My question is hence:

Is there a different way to obtain the Mellin transform of $G(z)$?

The asymptotic I expect is $G(z) \sim \frac{z}{\sqrt{ \log z}}$, for $z \to \infty$, which an asymptotic I have not found by any Mellin approach so far. Nor do the translation theorems in Flajolet's paper really seem to cover such a function. So maybe that's the problem.
PS The last part might be a question on its own respect, but it might cover the same issue. I might want to ask the second part as an own question.

Comment: Greetings from your former MSE collaborator (duplicate subtree compaction). I ran some numerical experiments before activating the Mellin transform machinery and I cannot get your initial harmonic sum to converge anywhere.

Comment: Dear @MarkoRiedel, thanks! I had only tried to plot the Mellin transform using Maple, which did not work. I will go through all my calculations carefully, maybe I made a mistake deriving the function. I derived the function also from the duplicate subtree compaction paper, using a method described in "Unbalanced subtrees in binary rooted ordered and unordered trees" by F. Disanto.

Comment: I do have the Mellin transform of your function but the Mellin inversion expansion about zero does not converge, which is not surprising. I wonder if you could post a link to that paper you mentioned?

Comment: @MarkoRiedel sorry, I should have included it the last time around. You can find it [here](http://www.emis.de/journals/SLC/), volume 68. I went through all calculations again, and sadly, I think I found the mistake: Right in the beginning. The replacement $\sqrt{1-4z+4z^{p+1}} \to \sqrt{1-4z+4^{-p}}$ may not be done in our case, as the effect of the substitution does not converge (the corresponding step is on page 6 in Disanto's paper). I'll look again at it tomorrow, and if that can't be fixed, I guess that would render my question useless.